# Revert all changes make to Mac OS X web sharing

Tags: php, mysql, mac, mac-osx

I've been messing about with apache2 php and mysql today and I've taken a few wrong turns. I'd rather install XAMPP than try to figure out all the problems.

I did a time machine backup a few days ago so can I delete some folders and restore good as new, or is there a feature were I can reinstall web sharing to its original state?

Comment: Has already been posted at [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/294236/revert-all-changes-make-to-mac-os-x-web-sharing) over here ...

Answer (score 0):

By default, your Time Machine backup won't contain files in /private, including /private/etc/apache2 which is where your configuration would likely be (if you're using the built-in apache). If you're using a desktop Mac (ie, non-server) you should be able to restore your default apache configuration by visiting /etc/apache2/original and replacing the files in respective directories.